# "Screen Recording" in LG Android

Tags: permissions, privacy, lg, disable-app, greenify

I have an LG V40, and in both Android 9 and 10, it seems that the "Screen Recording" app is always running, and not possible to keep it Stopped.

Greenify shows it as running in "Foreground":

[image]

If I force hibernation, seconds later it will be running in Foreground again.

It is not possible to disable this app, and it requires access to Camera and Microphone:

[image: IMG:]

These permissions cannot be removed either:

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Should I be concerned?
Is there any way I can fully disable this app?

My OS is European.

Comment: Hello. Unlike forums, our site follows a Q&A approach, and we also allow self-answering the question. You can choose to tick the check mark on the answer below if it has helped you out, or you can post a solution "as an answer below" that has worked for you. :-)

Comment: @Firelord - I know that... I was simply adding the output of the commands for reference, since I can't add to the comments below. Was it really necessary to remove it?..

Comment: @Firelord - and I don't agree with marking the question as Duplicate. The other question is about disabling apps downloaded in Google Play, without uninstalling them. That's NOT what I'm asking here. I wish there was a way to report these unnecessary changes by moderators..

Comment: Your edit about the error in the command was in response to the suggestion you received from user Aayush. However, in the comments on the answer, you later was able to resolve the issue with that suggestion. Since Aayush edited his answer to reflect your findings (the correct command that would not give the error and would work, that is), there is no value in keeping the error related info in your question.

Comment: I disagree with your disagreement about duplicate question. Whether an app is third party or a system app the answer to the linked question works equally on them. For what it is worth, one can just edit the title there from 'third party' to 'system' apps and the answer would remain applicable, valid and useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use adb to disable the app. And download a trusted  screen recorder.

**For installed apps:**
`adb shell pm list packages` should list all the packages on your device. Then use `adb shell pm disable <package_to_disable>`
to disable an installed app.

**For system apps:**
For system apps just the disable command is different  `adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 <package_to_disable>`

if you want to see the disabled apps use `adb shell pm list packages -d`

Take a look at this https://www.xda-developers.com/disable-system-app-bloatware-android/

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. `adb shell pm disable com.lge.gametools.gamerecorder` : "Security exception: Shell cannot change component state for com.lge.gametools.gamerecorder/null to 2". I put the whole output at the end of my question above.

Comment: Aah - this worked: `adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 com.lge.gametools.gamerecorder` : "Package com.lge.gametools.gamerecorder new state: disabled-user". Exactly as per what the article says :) -- if you edit your question to put "disable-user" instead of "disable", I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help  ;)